# How to get appendix (sub)sections not detailed in the main table of contents, but detailed at the beginning of appendix?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

In a report document with appendices, Appendix chapter's title should appear in the main table of contents without the section's, subsection's, etc., title it contains. At the beginning of the appendices, their should be a local table of contents only with the titles of sections, subsections, etc., it contains.

In practice, the following scheme:

```
\maintableofcontents
\chapter{Some Chapter}
\section{Some Section}
\section{An Other section}
\chapter{An Other Chapter}
\section{A Section, Again}
\section{An Other Section, Again}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendices}
\localtableofcontents
\section{Some Appendix}
\section{An Other Appendix}
```

should give something like(*):

```
Table of contents

Some Chapter
      1 Some section
      2 An Other section
An Other Chapter
      1 A Section, Again
      2 An Other Section, Again
Appendices

(here the main content)

Appendices

1 Some Appendix
2 An Other Appendix

(here the appendices' content)
```

How to get this?

(*) Note that, in this specific case, chapters have been redefined to be unnumbered.

Comment: My first attempt with this solution is inconclusive. I'll make a second try soon.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer for reducing the entries in the ToC.

```
...
\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}} % add this to your code
\chapter{Appendices}
...
```

The `\addtocontents{toc}{arg}` inserts `arg` into the ToC, which in the example above sets the `tocdepth` to 0 so that only chapters will be listed.